# How can I Implement a Control+Enter Keyboard Shortcut using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a button to be pushed when the user presses `ctrl+enter` in JavaScript. How can I achieve this? When using the below code and pressing `ctrl`, nothing happens. I'm also not sure how to use two keys at once.

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;

  alert('keypress event\n\n' + 'key: ' + keyName);
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

Comment: A web search on this would turn up lots and lots of results. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: I looked up 'How to implement keyboard shortcuts in html5` and it was a bunch of answers that used deprecated features.

Comment: highly doubt they are deprecated. SHow what you tried

Comment: Even if you saw deprecated features, you can still look into the documentation and see what alternatives are avalable (The link provided in the first comment)

Comment: I still can't find anything on multiple keypresses that works. How about giving me an answer now? @AlonEitan

Comment: @JordanBaron Sorry, but I can only answer questions with a [mcve], as this question is 1 vote away from getting closed as "Too broad" - Please include any attempt you tried to solve it yourself, and then maybe I, or other user, could provide a proper answer to your issue

Comment: @AlonEitan See my edited post

Answer (score 3):

The below code seems to work just fine. If anyone has a better solution feel free to answer!

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if(event.ctrlKey && event.key == "Enter") {
    alert("Ctrl+Enter key pressed");
  }
});
```